# How to execute an application using only its DLL ? C#.

Tags: c#, dll

I build a solution to a dll file , and now I am trying to run the application by another project after adding the dll to the project.
Is there a simple way of doing that?

**Update**

It is originally a Windows form application , but was build as a class library in order to user it from another project.
I want to have the same effect from the other project just as using its exe, but using my other project.

Is there a way of calling Main of the dll program?

Comment: What does the "entry" point into the Assembly (DLL) look like?

Comment: Please people write an explanation of why you downvote on post. Especialy when it's new person. Sounds like everyone downvote only because it's your first time here. Hate that.

Comment: What does this DLL do? It's not an executable, only an assembly that you can reference and use it's public members (i.e. events/methods/properties) inside your project.

Comment: Are you new to C#? There are different types of executables, it could be a console application, a windows forms, a WPF application. What type of application are you trying to build? It woild be good if you follow some book to get started

Comment: To all the closers you should of given this a little more time. His question is poorly written, but he might be aiming for a plug-in architecture and doesn't know how to express himself.

Comment: @Ramhound You should read articles from Joel, Atwood, and others about the fine line between ensuring questions improve the community and making sure stackoverflow is not an elitist hangout.

Comment: "Is there a way of calling Main of the dll program?" It's just a static method of a class. Why can't you call it?

Answer (score 3):

Reference the DLL or project in your other project and run what ever you want to run from it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this definitively we would need to know what your DLL contains.  But supposing that it contains a `Program` class with a `Main()` method, you can run your program by calling `Program.Main()`.